# HTML Combobox disappearing right after appearing

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple web page which looks like this.

[image]

When clicked on the Load button, it should show up a small form under the combobox (the id given to that form is `frmUpdateService`).

The problem is when I click on the load button, it shows the form but it gets disappeared immediately after showing up!

Here's the HTML code of the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body_services">

<?php

include_once 'DatabaseHandler.php';
$db = DatabaseHandler::getInstance();

//loading taxi service names for updating combobox
$queryLoadSids = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM taxi_services ORDER BY SID");
$queryLoadSids->execute();
$dropdown = "<select name='serviceID'>";
while ($row = $queryLoadSids->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['SID']}'>{$row['Name']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['btnload']))
{
    $param = $_POST['serviceID'];

    $queryLoadToUpdate = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM taxi_services WHERE SID = :serviceID");
    $queryLoadToUpdate->bindParam(':serviceID', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $queryLoadToUpdate->execute();
    $results = $queryLoadToUpdate->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $loadedSID = $results["SID"];
    $loadedName = $results["Name"];
    $loadedCost = $results["Cost"];
    $loadedActive = $results["Active"];
}

?>

<div id="tasks">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="add" href="#">Add a new taxi service</a></li>
        <li><a id="update" href="#">Update a taxi service</a></li>
        <li><a id="delete" href="#">Delete a taxi service</a></li>
        <li><a id="view" href="#">View taxi services</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form id="cmbServiceIDs" name="sids">
<table width="380" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="serviceId">Select the Service ID</label></td>
    <td><?php echo $dropdown; ?></td>
    <td><input id="load" type="submit" value="Load" name="btnload" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<form id="frmUpdateService" name="Update" action="" method="post">
<table width="300" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="sid">Service ID</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" value="<?php echo $loadedSID; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $loadedName; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="cost">Cost</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cost" value="<?php echo $loadedCost; ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="active">Active</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="active" value="<? echo $loadedActive; ?>" <?php echo $loadedActive ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel" /> <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And I use jQuery for appearing show/hide effects.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#frmUpdateService").hide();
    $("#cmbServiceIDs").hide();

    $("#update").click(function()
    {
        $("#cmbServiceIDs").slideDown("slow");
        $("#frmUpdateService").hide();
    });
    $("#load").click(function()
    {
        $("#frmUpdateService").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's related to using a `submit` and not a `button`...

Comment: Yes I use submit as input type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the submit button, which POSTs the page to the server, and reloads the response (which causes the line that hides the form to run).

Either change this

```
<input id="load" type="submit" value="Load" name="btnload" />
```

to this

```
<input id="load" type="button" value="Load" name="btnload" />
```

or change your click event to something like this:

```
$("#load").click(function(e)
{
    $("#frmUpdateService").fadeIn("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Both your methods work great :) Thank you for that but I have one other question regarding this. When the Load button is clicked, it's supposed to take the selected value from the combobox item, run a quesry based on that and retrieve some details from a DB and display them in the form's textboxes. I've written the PHP code for that. (Please see above, starting from the line `if(isset($_POST['btnload']))`) If I put button as the input type, does that PHP code get executed? 'cause when I did that, those details didnt show up inside the textboxes.

Comment: The PHP code won't run because now the form isn't being sent to the server. The problem is, when it is sent to the server as an HTTP POST (and returned again) the browser will reload it, causing the form to be hidden again. Options: 1. Use AJAX to post the form values and populate the fields using javascript so the page doesn't change (libraries like jQuery make this a little easier) 2. Remove all the javascript that hides and shows the form and use PHP to do it, causing a POST every time (Docs on jQuery Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

The `#load` button does what you ask and then goes on submitting the page, refreshing everything. You should either use a normal button or some kind of clickable div, or use `preventDefault()`inside the clickhandler of your `#load` button.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of these two statements:

```
$("#frmUpdateService").hide();
$("#cmbServiceIDs").hide();
```

They get executed each page load. This is something that could be solved nicely with Ajax.

If you wan't to solve this using full postbacks you should make sure the correct html, including what is visible and not visible is taken care of server side.